# Istio Ingress Gateway: 404 NR route_not_found

Tags: http-status-code-404, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I would like to configure an Istio ingress gateway which routes traffic to different services based on the prefix of the HTTP path.

For example HTTP traffic path **/myservice** shall be routed to service **myservice**.

I have created the following YAML configuration so far:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: microservices
  labels:
    app: myservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myservice
          image: myservice-node
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3002
          imagePullPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: microservices
spec:
  ports:
    - nodePort: 32015
      port: 3002
      targetPort: 3002
  selector:
    app: myservice
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
  namespace: microservices
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: crossway
  namespace: microservices
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - mygateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /myservice
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 3002
        host: myservice.microservices.svc.cluster.local
```

Sending a request to http://192.168.99.111:31878/myservice yielded a 404 error as can be seen below.

```
$ export INGRESS_HOST=$(minikube ip)
$ export INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o     jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}')
$ echo "INGRESS_HOST=$INGRESS_HOST, INGRESS_PORT=$INGRESS_PORT"
INGRESS_HOST=192.168.99.111, INGRESS_PORT=31878
$ curl -I http://192.168.99.111:31878/myservice
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
date: Sat, 17 Apr 2021 10:54:43 GMT
server: istio-envoy
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

In the log file of the ingress gateway I found the following error message:

```
[2021-04-17T10:54:43.408Z] "HEAD /myservice HTTP/1.1" 404 NR route_not_found - "-" 0 0 0 - "172.17.0.1" "curl/7.64.0" "3b11c571-4372-9b4a-971e-25af260eeba3" "192.168.99.111:31878" "-" - - 172.17.0.4:8080 172.17.0.1:42458 - -
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain the [solution of Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67138931/5730279) a bit more I added:

#### Issue: "404 Not Found" caused by istio-envoy "404 NR route_not_found"

When the routing from *Gateway* to *VirtualService* is not configured correctly using `hosts` property you will get a response status **404 Not Found** as response from `server: istio-envoy` (response header) like:

```
$ curl -I http://192.168.99.111:31878/myservice
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
date: Sat, 17 Apr 2021 10:54:43 GMT
server: istio-envoy
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

That is caused by the ingress gateway (`istio-envoy`) which can't find the route. Thus you saw such an error-message in envoy's [access logs with *response-flag* `NR`](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log/usage#config-access-log-format-response-flags):

> **NR:** No [route configured](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/http/http_routing#arch-overview-http-routing) for a given request in addition to 404 response code, or no matching filter chain for a downstream connection.

Like given part `404 NR route_not_found` in your log-except.

#### Fix: add a wildcard-route

To make the internal service (virtual host) reachable from outside, like from a browser, you have to define a wildcard-route from `*` to `*`. See explained in Istio docs [Accessing ingress services using a browser](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#accessing-ingress-services-using-a-browser):

> To work around this problem for simple tests and demos, **use a wildcard `*` value for the `host` in the *Gateway* and *VirtualService*** configurations.

#### See also

The official Istio guide: [Configure Istio Ingress Gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/microservices-istio/istio-ingress-gateway/) also includes steps to test the ingress gateway configuration.

For observation of a `404 NR` with Istio there are  similar issues reported:

- isto: [Issue #26562: "GET / HTTP/2" 404 NR when trying trying to go via ingressgateway](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/26562)
- envoyproxy: [Issue #12936: Connection closed after a 404 + NR](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/12936)

Answer (score 5):

I could resolve the problem by changing the value of hosts from "host.docker.internal" to "*".